# Python- my code works if i use raw_input but not if I use a random number

Tags: python, random

Basically I made a programm which should generate a random number, than you have to guess the number.

Problem is: if I use

```
N = raw_input()
```

It works, but if I use

```
N= randrange(1,100)
```

of

```
N=3
```

It does not work! He always prints "The number should be bigger" even if I insert the right number!
Any ideas? Thank you!
Here's the full code:

```
from random import randrange
N = raw_input() #randrange(1,100)
tentavivi=10
vittoria=False
for i in range(0,tentavivi):
    n = raw_input("Insert the number")
    if n==N:
        vittoria=True
        break
    elif n<N:
        print("the number is bigger")
    else:
        print("the number is smaller")
if vittoria:
    print("Bravo!")
else:
    print("no! bad boy!")
```

Comment: `raw_input()` return `str` and `randrange(1,100)` return `int` use: `str(randrange(1,100))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the input to a number

```
N = int(raw_input())
...
...
n = int(raw_input("Insert the number"))
```

Comment: Thank you again. May I ask, is there a way to input an integer directly without doing the int(raw_input()) thing?

Comment: No, it isn't. Well, to be honest, there is `input` but using that is a security hole.

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input()` returns a *string*, not an integer. Comparing integers and strings will never result in a `True`.

You'll have to make your comparisons using the same type; either convert your random number to a string first, or convert all `raw_input()` results to integers.

With:

```
N = str(randrange(1, 100))
```

the other lines where you compare `N` with `raw_input()` results make comparisons between strings.

This differs from languages like JavaScript or Perl, where digits in a string will automatically be coerced to a number when compared with another number. Python, on the whole, will try to avoid doing implicit conversions like these. (The exception is operations combining  `unicode` and `str` values in Python 2, a mistake corrected in Python 3).

Comment: Converting to a string is a Bad Idea. OP doesn't want lexical comparison, and the original code only "works" coincidentally, when all of the guesses have the same number of digits as the actual answer.

Comment: I was illustrating a quick fix, but missed the `<` comparison later on.

Answer (score 2):

If you enter 3 in `N=raw_input()`, your `N` will be `'3'`, which is a string, not `3`, which is an int. And `'3'` is not equal to `3`. You can use `int(N)` to convert a string to an integer, and `int('3')` will be equal to `3`.